# WPF error : The name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm getting this problem building a WPF project

> The name does not exist in the namespace

Everything I’ve looked at says you should

> Change the namespace and the project name, build, change them back
>   Change the build from 86 to 64, build,  and back Tried removing the
>   reference and letting ReSharper re-instate the reference Tried
>   excluding the file, build, then include the file again

None of the above worked.

I have checked that each referenced class has only one instance of it throughout the whole solution – ruling out named duplicates

The references in question are all references within the one DLL – all namespaces within this dll so it’s not like there is a cross dll issue of any sort.

Your thoughts or suggestions at this point are appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste some code/error message?

Comment: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" are these namespaces present in xaml

Comment: Can you confirm that resharper is not loading the DLL from obj folder? Resharper often Imports the wrong dll

Comment: It be wierd but restart Your Vsual Studio. It is common problem. Do You use VS 2015?

Comment: Yes, those namespaces exist. Not sure about how to check what is loaded - but I'll dig deeper.  Yes, VS2015. Have restarted many times without resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I to assume that You have this error in XAML file.

I thing it is very common problem with WPF and Visual Studio 2015.For example I have this error when I use DevExpress dlls

My suggestions is to try this:

1. Restart Visual Studio - it is weird but frequently it works. I don't now way it works.
2. Use F5 and run the program  instead of build them (F6). Sometimes when You compile app the error disappear and app runs. It is also weird, but in my case it works

This not resolve the problem but it helps exclude the problem with IDE

Comment: It did run without complaint - but that doesn't help me to ensure I maintain build integrity when I check the code back into source control